# Better int declration

Tags: java, int

If I have to store 3 integer values and would like to just retrieve the same , no calculation is required.Which one of the following would be a better option?

```
int i,j,k;
   or 
int [] arr = new int[3];
```

Array would be allocating 3 continuous blocks of memory (after allocation of space by JVM) or randomly assigning variables to some memory location (which I guess would consume lesser time for JVM as compared to array).

Apologies if the question is too trivial.

Comment: use the first one and don't call your variables `i`,`j` and `k` use meaningful names. No one would like to find a codebase where all variables are named like `a[12348]`

Comment: The difference in the memory impact is what is trivial.  What is vital is to realize that it is FAR more important to think about the impact this choice makes on the HUMANS reading your code.  The computer really doesn't care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:  It depends.

---

You shouldn't think too much about the performance implications for this case.  the performance difference between the two is not big enough to notice.

What you really need to be on the look out for is readability and maintainability.

---

if `i`, `j`, and `k`, all essentially mean the same thing, and you're going to be using them the same way, and you feel like you might want to iterate over them, then it might make sense to use an array, so that you can iterate over them more easily.

if they're different values, with different meanings, and you're going to be using them differently, than it does not makes sense to include them in an array.  They should each have their own identity, and their own **descriptive** variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Choose whichever makes most sense semantically:

- If these variables are three *for a fundamental reason* (maybe they are coordinates in the 3D space of a 3D game engine), then use three separate variables (because making, say, a *4D game engine* is not a trivial change).
- If these variables are three now but they could be trivially changed to be four tomorrow, it's reasonable to consider an array (or, better yet, a new type that contains them).

---

In terms of performance, traditionally local variables are faster than arrays. Under specific circumstances, the array may be allocated on the stack. Under specific circumstances, bound checks can be removed.

But don't make decisions based on performance, unless you have first done everything else correctly first *and* you have thorough tests *and* this particular piece of code is a performance-critical hot-spot *and* you're sure that it is the bottleneck of your application at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how would you access them. Array is of course an overhead, because you will first calculate a reference to a value and then get it. So if these values are totally unrelated, array is bad, and it may even count as code obfuscation. But naming variables like `i`, `j`, `k` is sort of obfuscation, too. Obfuscation is better to do automatically at build stage, there are tools like Proguard™ which can do it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but **most probably**, using **distinct variables** is the way to go.

In general, **don't do micro-optimizations**. Nobody will ever notice any difference in performance. Readable and maintainable code is what really matters in high-level languages.

See [this article on micro-optimizations](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).

Answer (score 1):

The two are not the same at all and are for different purpose.
in the first example you gave `int i,j,k;` you are pushing the values on to the stack,
The stack is for short term use and small data sizes i.e. function call arguments and iterator states.

The second example you gave `int [] arr = new int[3];` the `new` keyword is allocating actual memory for the heap hat was giving to the process by the operating system.

The stack is optimized for short term use and all (most) all CPUs have a registers that are dedicated to point at the stack location and base making the stack a grate place for small dirty variables.  The  stack is also limited in size (by theory), its only a few KB in size (average case).

The heap on he other hand is proper memory allocation for large data types and proper memory management.

So, the two may be used for the same thing but it dose not mean it's right.
Arrays/Objects/Dicts go in allocated memory from he heap, function arguments (and iterator indexes usually) go on the stack.

Comment: This is completely true.  Yes the allocation is different.  However, that difference is RARELY more significant to the bottom line than readability.  Smarter people than me have been teaching this for a long time.  Here's one:  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization